# How does "Someone is typing" feature actually works in chat applications?

Tags: ajax, http, websocket, long-polling, system-design

I read a lot of questions around the same use case but couldn't find any proper answer on Google.
One theory is the Server keep a long poll at sender (A) and whenever a typing event is triggered it sends update to server.
On the receiver's end (B), it keep another long polling request to the server and as soon as the server get's update from sender(A) it sends it to the receiver (B).

But this seems dubious, in the sense that servers have to handle so many (~millions) of long polling requests at any given time and will slow down the servers.

Comment: These events are throttled down by the sender (one every second or so). Sending one event per key pressed would indeed suck up quite a bit of bandwidth. Pusher offers a so-called real-time notification system that can allow you to effortlessly squander the needed resources. It's a costly little toy nevertheless, but then again the Internet is all about spoiled brats eating up resources like there's no tomorrow.

Answer (score 1):

Most chat systems probably keep open P2P TCP connections with their clients.
This solves many issues in chat systems such as avoiding polling on multiple scenarios, not only the ones you mentioned but receiving new messages as well.

I recommend checking out [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vvhC64hQZMk)

In this type of design "Someone is typing" becomes just one new type of event, it has a SRC and a DST and the Backend infrastructure takes care of routing the event to the correct websocket for the DST client.

I imagine as others mentioned that the clients will throttle the events as to avoid network traffic on every key press.